# How can I see how many people are checked in somewhere via the FourSquare API?

Tags: javascript, html, foursquare

I am searching for a method to see how many people are checked in somewhere. Example: There are 73 people checked-in via swarm in the library. How can I get this information through the API?  I couldn't find anything in the api that could do this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me Four Square has documentation for Real time api, https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime, otherwise it looks like they use swarm as well,
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins,
I hope this helps.